# Maketitle error

Tags: errors, titles

Why do I constantly get this error:
There's no line here to end. \maketitle

When I learned to use latex I was told to use \maketitle where I want to have my title placed. What is written in the title is defined by \title. Like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,abstracton]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}               %Zeichencodierung Text
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                     %Schriftsatz Dokument

%%Language settings
\usepackage[english]{babel}                  %ngerman for German
\usepackage{csquotes}                        %[babel,quotes=english]
\usepackage{caption}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}}
%\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}   % only works when not using babel

%%Paper adjustments
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}                        %if problems with importing .eps graphics
%\usepackage{a4wide}                         %obsolete and replaced by geometry
\usepackage[a4paper,bottom=3.1cm]{geometry}  %also with command \geometry{options}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{titling}


\begin{document}

\title{\LARGE Advanced Course \\ [1em] \huge \textbf{Tools}}
\author{Muster1 \hspace{1cm} Muster2}
\date{\\[1em] {Today} \\ [0.8cm] Supervisor Dr. Muster3 \\ [0.5cm] Institut \\ University of Whatsoever}

\clearpage
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand\abstractname{Abstract}
\renewcommand\tablename{Table}
\newpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: lose the `\\[1em]` at the start of your date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `\\` (inside `\date`) when TeX is in vertical mode. TeX has the vertical and the horizontal modes. Horizontal mode is for putting letters into lines and assembling those into paragraphs, vertical mode is for putting those paragraphs and other things onto the page. `\\` is a horizontal mode command that breaks the current line inside a paragraph. The error you are getting, no line to end, is exactly right: you have not begun a line, i.e. entered horizontal mode, yet.

Use `\vspace{1em}` instead of `\\[1em]` as vspace is a vertical mode macro that will function exactly how you want it to.

Comment: `\null` isn't a (supported) latex command for use in documents (and does not start horizontal mode so will do nothing here)

Comment: Would `\hbox{}` be the proper thing to use, then? I was under the misconception that `\null` simply expanded to `\hbox{}`.

Comment: `\null` does expand to `\hbox{}` that is why it does not work.

Comment: The reason that we always ask people to provide MWE in questions is so that people can test answers. Did you try adding `\null`?

Comment: I'm not at a computer right now, but I'll rush to one to try as you suggest.

Comment: I tried it and wrote `\null` just before the `\\[1em]` in `\date`. The result was an added vertical space and the error message still remained. Replacing `\\[1em]` with `\vspace{1em}` solved my problem: the vertical spacing stayed the same and the error disappeared. Thanks

Comment: @Lucas yes (That's why I edited the answer after you accepted it so future readers wouldn't be confused:-)

Comment: Okay, I understand. `\hbox` does not enter horizontal mode, but if I put `\mbox{}` before `\\ ` it does work properly. I guess this is why LaTeX macros are preferred over TeX primitives. Thanks for editing the answer.